# Flag weight default value

Tags: discussion, flag-weight

So I just read that [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) and I was just wondering if there is a practical reason for the default flag weight value to be 100.

Why doesn't it start at 0, is there a logic I don't get behind all that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Why doesn't it start at 0, is there a logic I don't get behind all that?

If the flag weight drops below zero, [all flags from the user are suppressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80178/133693). Setting the flag weight to zero for a new user would mean that their first mistake in flagging would result in flags being suppressed - so the team has set the default flag weight to a reasonable limit.

Besides, having something above zero from start is kinda nice, isn't it? :)

Comment: Yes I'm not criticizing this system I was just curious :). For the suppression thing I guess a declined flags counter vs a useful flags counter could have done the trick.

Comment: Don't think counters would be a good idea - how do you set the limit? Setting an arbitrary number after which flags get suppressed wouldn't be very nice. With this you get a decent cushion & the cushion increases with each good flag @talnicolas

Answer (score 0):

The fact that flag weight starts at 100 tells me that you should be able to compare two users' flag weights as if they were percentages. So having a weight of 320 means your flags are 2.133x stronger than those of someone with a weight of 150, and a flag weight of 20 means your flags are worth a fifth of a new user's flags. This would explain why a weight of 0 supresses flags.

Or maybe they just picked 100 to fool people into thinking exactly this.